# Map reducing Scanamo query conditions

Tags: scala, amazon-dynamodb, alpakka

I'll dive right in. I am using `ScanamoAlpakka`.

I have the following:

```
Map(
 'field1 -> value1,
 'field2 -> value2,
  and so on...
)
```

The goal is to iterate the map and remove any empty values. Once the empty values are removed, I need to transform each key/value pair into a query condition based on its type.

Like so:

```
mapObject
 .collect({
   case (key, Some(value: DateRange)) => key between (value.after and value.before)
   case (key, Some(value)) => key -> value
 })
 .reduce(_ and _)
```

This does not work because the conditions outlined above do not immediately become objects of a query condition class. I have been looking through the SDK and have had difficulty finding a class that would transform the key/value pairs into a queryable condition.

I have tried using `Condition(key, value)` which appears to work, however when done in this format it appears all of the implicits that apply for `DynamoFormat` are lost, as I get the following error:

`Error:(22, 45) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.gu.scanamo.query.ConditionExpression[(Symbol, Any)]
        case (key, Some(value)) => Condition(key -> value)`

Comment: I do not see any parent trait for `RangeKeyCondition` (which is created with `between`) and `KeyEquals`. However there is a `ConditionExpression` typeclass. But for that you will have to store all of the conditions in a heterogeneos list, like `HList` from shapeless.